# Large Deviations on Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization, constraint

I am not an expert with Mathematica, and I really need your help. 
I am trying to do some large deviation theory with Mathematica and I have to minimize a piecewise function.

How do I minimize a Function $I(a\cdot q,q)$ with respect to $q$, given that $q>f(a)$?

My goal is then to get the $q_{\min}$ which minimizes $I(a\cdot q,q)$ in the region $q>f(a)$ and then compute $J(a)=I(a\cdot q_{\min},q_{\min})$.

I have no code yet, but I guess from a logical point of view is quite simple. Do some of you could help me with the right way to write this?

Comment: `NMinimize[]` could work, but it would be really good to have an explicit example from you so there's something to discuss.